# Memory usage issue of Numpy Array having list object

Tags: python, list, numpy, memory

I am working on a streaming application where I need to send data with least memory footprint. My data (a list object) is wrapped in a numpy array but I am getting same memory size even after reducing data from list. For example

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import sys
>>> from pympler.asizeof import asizeof
>>> x = np.full((299,299,3),120)
>>> x.nbytes
2145624
>>> a1 = [x, '1','2']
>>> sys.getsizeof(a1)
88
>>> y = np.full((25000,3),120) # creating a smaller array with less data as compare to x
>>> y.nbytes
600000
>>> a2 = [y, '1','2']
>>> sys.getsizeof(a2)
88
>>> a2 =[[y], '1','2']
>>> sys.getsizeof(a2)
88
>>> a3 = np.array(a2, dtype = object)
>>> a3.nbytes
24
>>> a2 =[[y,y,y,y], '1','2']
>>> sys.getsizeof(a2)
88
>>> a4 = np.array(a2,dtype = object)
>>> a4.nbytes
24
```

How much data I increase or decrease inside the list like in a2 = [[y,y,y,y,y...100 times],'1','2'] and passed to numpy array or even in list itself the memory remains same. What I am doing wrong here and what is a correct way to get memory size for such objects?

Comment: `a1`, `a2` are just pointers to the data, as is `[y,y,y,y]`.

Comment: Identifying memory usage of a list requires understanding what's in the list.  `getsizeof` is  not much help.

Comment: To the broader question: if your goal is a small transfer file, isn't all that matters the compressed size anyway? This may not have a strong relation to the uncompressed size. And it would solve the getting the list size problem too -- save it in the format you want, and that will be the size, regardless of how list are represented within Python. (In general, though, for large data streams of the same type, I bet the smallest numpy type saved in a compressed file will be optimal and easy.)